# c++ singlton vs static class vs extern vs namspace

Tags: c++, game-engine

so I'm trying to make my own simple 2d game engine for the first time and I have some objects which I only need one instance of them like "Window" and "Event" for example and I've seen different ways to make it so only one instance of an object is valid at a given time so there is no need to pass pointers and refrences and stuff everywhere and get the code messy...
so from what I've seen so far there is 4 ways to do it :
using singlton or static class or extern object or a static object inside a namspace
my questions are:
what should I use ?
when to use anyone of them and what is a good and bad practice ?
thanks in advance and sorry if my question is a bit silly

Comment: Singleton pattern utilizes a static object to be implemented in c++. It's usually the best option for only needing one instance of a class to be used

Comment: Asking which one is best and what are good practices tend to attract opinionated answers so they are deemed off-topic here.

Comment: Singleton approach is only worthwhile if you can’t even imagine ever needing a second object of the same type in some future extension of your program.  I wouldn’t use it for Window or Event types, since it’s easy to imagine that in a few weeks you might realize that you need to instantiate a second one, and then you’ll have a major redesign/revalidate project on your hands.  Better to aim on the first design for one that can support what you’re likely to end up needing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of not having to pass pointers/references to the same object everywhere a global or namespace-scope pointer is the simplest. That object it points to doesn't have to be a singleton.